# NotFound route always showing with static routes - [React Router 4]

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux, react-router-v4

How can I define a notFound component with `React Router 4` and static routes?

I use the `next`version of `react-router-redux`. So, in my client:

```
export default function appRoutes(history) {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        {routes.map((route, key) => (
          <Route key={key} {...route} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}
```

And routes is:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: App
  },
  {
    path: '/:lang/chat',
    component: Chat
  },
  {
    path: '/:lang',
    component: Listing
  },
  ...
  {
    path: '*',
    component: NotFound,
    status: 404
  },
];
```

With this approach, the component not found is always showing along with the matched route.

I have read that instead of wrapping the `appRoutes` method described above, with a div, I have to use Switch. But with this approach, the routes never match.

**EDIT**

I want to display, for example, App component and Listing component at the same time but the NotFound is also displaying.

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. I have removed from static routes the `App` component and placed before and then I used `Switch` to render only one route.

```
export default function appRoutes(history) {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route path='/' component={App} />
        <Switch>
          {routes.map((route, key) => (
            <Route key={key} {...route} />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

React router V4 displays all routes that match. If you would like to display just one use Switch component.

Comment: But what about If I have the "/" route, which display ´App´ component, where I have the header and then I have the listing component, "/:lang", below the header? What you say it's true, with Switch It only render the first match component, which is App.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to but if I correctly understand you, use exact attribute.

Comment: If I want to render `App` component and `Listing` component when the url is https://route/en/, I have to use exact attribute? And what about the component `notFound`? It will not display? Do I have to use exact in all my defined static router components? Thanks